# How to perform multiple updates in database through entity beans using hibernate...refer to code

Tags: java, hibernate, javabeans, sql-update

Q: HOw to perform multiple update in entity class using hibernate in java, when i use only a single set***() method yhen my code runs well and update the criminal tble but when i add some more method to update of entity class as setGender() it says "An Exception occured: Could not execute JDBC batch update" please need immidiate help

```
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Transaction"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="entity.Criminal"%>

<%@page import="hibdao.HibernateUtil"%>

<%
try{
  String Name=request.getParameter("Name");
  String Criminalid=request.getParameter("CriminalId");
        if(Criminalid=="")throw new Exception("Please provide a Criminal Id.");
        String Gender=request.getParameter("Gender");
        String Height=request.getParameter("Height");
        String Weight=request.getParameter("Weight");
        String PStationId=request.getParameter("PStationId");
        String CrimeLevel=request.getParameter("CrimeLevel");
        String Status=request.getParameter("Status");

       /* out.println("id="+Criminalid);
        out.println("name="+Name);
        out.println("g="+Gender);
        out.println("Height="+Height);
        out.println("Weight="+Weight);
        out.println("PStationId="+PStationId);
        out.println("CrimeLevel="+CrimeLevel);
        out.println("Status="+Status);

        */

        Session s=HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
        Criminal c=(Criminal)s.get(Criminal.class,Criminalid);
        c.setName(Name);
        c=(Criminal)s.get(Criminal.class,Criminalid);

        c.setName(Name);
        //sc.setGender(Gender);//this line create the proble...i.e. if we write morethan 1
//  set methods it says "An Exception occured:  Could not execute JDBC batch update" due to 
//catch block...please help...when executing single update it run ok

               s.update(c);
               t.commit();


               }catch(Exception e)
               {
               out.print("An Exception occured:\t"+e.getMessage());
               }


        %>
```

Comment: You should never put as much java code in a JSP ! Use a servlet where unit testing will be simpler. And please, do not use Capitalized names for your variables it confuses even SO formatter ... BTW, I see 2 almost consecutive `s.get(Criminal.class,Criminalid);`. The second should never occur there.

Comment: I tried to replicate the same thing in my workspace but using dao, it does not create an issues, try to move this logic to a servlet/dao at the server side, it might help